# A divided country

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

> The TRIM GAL exited a FORD CAR. She wore a LONG LEI and on her WAY DOWN to the beach bar ordered LIME WATER in a glass with a LOW RIM. An ANT hopped from a RICK up a candle's WICK and all was DONE.

Choosing sixteen words from above, make ten nouns with a common property. No anagramming is needed, just placing side by side like WATERWAY or even just one like CAR and some of the sixteen words may be used more than once.

Comment: Nice. AN will work instead of ANT allowing RIM to be economised

Comment: Yes, also thought later would be nice written as a Limerick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are talking about

> Ireland

The ten words are

> DONEGAL, WICKLOW, GALWAY, DOWN, LONGFORD, WATERFORD, LIMERICK, CARLOW, LEITRIM, ANTRIM

Which are

> counties in Ireland.

The title is a clue as well because

> it mentions how Ireland is divided into the Republic of Ireland and Northern Ireland.

Comment: That was offaly fast - well done.

Comment: I wonder if any one could explain why Verynaq doesn't sink even though it's in the middle of water.

Comment: Nope. It's a total mystery and no one has any idea.